# How to mantain the LTPA Token after closing the application?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I have implemented `WASLTPAAuthentication` (with WASLTPALoginModule and Realm) and it works well.
I can call my JAX-RS and they took the identity by the cookie.

My problem is: after I tap the Home button and open the menu of recent applications to swipe and quit the application, then once I open it again the session is destroyed and the cookie is lost and I need to insert my credentials and login again.

Is there a way to prevent this? Do I need to store the cookie on the localStorage in some way?

Comment: Just for clarity, when you say "I can call my JAX-RS and they took the identity by the cookie" you mean you are making a call to an adapter to make the request and the adapter is what is sending the cookie, correct?

Comment: No, i didn't try to put the cookie in some adapter attribute, i just make a $.ajax() call by using jQuery XHR call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like even though your LTPA cookie is still valid, when you close the application and the session dies, the cookies are being cleared. You will need to save the LTPA cookie in local storage and then set the cookie manually if you want it to use it for multiple sessions.

The LTPA cookie is included in the attributes object of the UserIdentity returned after successfully logging into the WASLTPARealm, so you should already have access to it. Its just a matter of saving and retrieving it.

Comment: The LTPA token is in the response at response.responseJSON.userInfo.<Realm Name>.attributes.LtpaToken.  You can save that and after app restart, explicitly set the cookie in any call to $.ajax().  But from a Worklight perspective, there doesn't seem to be a way to use the token to login.  I don't see a way to set a cookie when you submit the login form.  I tried WL.Client.addGlobalHeader("Cookie", "LtpaToken=" + value); and challengeHandler.submitLoginForm("/j_security_check", {headers : {Cookie: "LtpaToken=" + value}}, and neither resulted in an LtpaToken cookie being sent to the server.

Comment: This is a correct observation. From a $.ajax-cookie perspective, the storing and retrieving of the cookie from local storage will work. However from a Worklight perspective this is not the case. Once you have closed the app, the session is killed and the user will need to log in again. You cannot use the LTPA token to log into Worklight in this case. You would have to save the user credentials in local storage and then send them on app startup if you wanted to have some sort of auto-login.